c++ summ up some float values using 2 decimals
I try to sum upp some float values in c++, 65769.59+13.95 = 65783.54 using calculator, but i get 65783.55 in my c++ code why?
I tried
float t_amount = 13.95;
float total_amount = 65769.59;
char buf[20];
sprintf_s(buf, "%.2f", t_amount);
total_amount += (float)atof(buf);


Because floating point arithmetic is not mathematically exact. You often get small rounding errors. You could try using double instead of float. The rounding errors will be smaller.

Does the same floating-point calculation producing different results when performed twice indicate IEEE 754 non-conformance?

Don't do that, just add all the numbers no matter the number of decimals. Only when you print the values, change the format to only print two decimals. Besides the lower precision of float, your conversion will make it even worse.

If you print all the digits in the inputs, you will see that they are actually 13.94999980926513671875 and 65769.59375.

@molbdnilo  Additionally, if all the digits of atof(buf)  (or of (float)atof(buf)) are printed, it would be seen that its value will not be exactly 13.95 - but the OP seems to be assuming it will be.
